# Raspberry pi isn't supporting VNC over my home network

Tags: raspberry-pi, vnc-viewer

I set up my raspberry pi to support vnc and was able to access it when it is connected to my mobile hotspot. However, I'm not able to access it using WiFi at home.

I do get the new IP address after my raspberry Pi connects to my home network. But when I try to access that IP address on my laptop (connected to the home network), there is no response and it vnc eventually gets a timeout.

Is there any WiFi configuration to be changed to support vnc?

Answer (score 0):

1.PING your raspberry pi's IP, make sure to get PING responses.
2.Check your raspberry pi listen status by command `netstat -nltup` or `ss  -nltup`, make sure port listening, for vnc protocol port normally is 5900 (TCP or UDP).